# How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search, recursion

Is there any fast way to get all subarrays where a key value pair was found in a multidimensional array? I can't say how deep the array will be.

Simple example array:

```
$arr = array(0 => array(id=>1,name=>"cat 1"),
             1 => array(id=>2,name=>"cat 2"),
             2 => array(id=>3,name=>"cat 1")
);
```

When I search for key=name and value="cat 1" the function should return:

```
array(0 => array(id=>1,name=>"cat 1"),
      1 => array(id=>3,name=>"cat 1")
);
```

I guess the function has to be recursive to get down to the deepest level.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Code:

```
function search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
            $results[] = $array;
        }

        foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key, $value));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

$arr = array(0 => array(id=>1,name=>"cat 1"),
             1 => array(id=>2,name=>"cat 2"),
             2 => array(id=>3,name=>"cat 1"));

print_r(search($arr, 'name', 'cat 1'));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => cat 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => cat 1
        )

)
```

If efficiency is important you could write it so all the recursive calls store their results in the same temporary `$results` array rather than merging arrays together, like so:

```
function search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();
    search_r($array, $key, $value, $results);
    return $results;
}

function search_r($array, $key, $value, &$results)
{
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return;
    }

    if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
        $results[] = $array;
    }

    foreach ($array as $subarray) {
        search_r($subarray, $key, $value, $results);
    }
}
```

The key there is that `search_r` takes its fourth parameter by reference rather than by value; the ampersand `&` is crucial.

FYI: If you have an older version of PHP then you have to specify the pass-by-reference part in the *call* to `search_r` rather than in its declaration. That is, the last line becomes `search_r($subarray, $key, $value, &$results)`.

Answer (score 77):

How about the [SPL](http://php.net/spl) version instead? It'll save you some typing:

```
// I changed your input example to make it harder and
// to show it works at lower depths:

$arr = array(0 => array('id'=>1,'name'=>"cat 1"),
             1 => array(array('id'=>3,'name'=>"cat 1")),
             2 => array('id'=>2,'name'=>"cat 2")
);

//here's the code:

    $arrIt = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));

 foreach ($arrIt as $sub) {
    $subArray = $arrIt->getSubIterator();
    if ($subArray['name'] === 'cat 1') {
        $outputArray[] = iterator_to_array($subArray);
    }
}
```

What's great is that basically the same code will iterate through a directory for you, by using a RecursiveDirectoryIterator instead of a RecursiveArrayIterator. SPL is the roxor.

The only bummer about SPL is that it's badly documented on the web. But several PHP books go into some useful detail, particularly Pro PHP; and you can probably google for more info, too.

Comment: This works like a charm and I plan use it again for similar problems :D The only weird part is in the foreach and using the getSubIterator function on the RecursiveIteratorIterator instead of the $sub variable. I thought it was a typo at first but it's the right way! thanks Jared.

Comment: Thank you for solution. Where do we get the "id"? From $outputArray?

Comment: Thanks,very straight forward solution,but don't know about performance ??.

Comment: how to unset the found element(could be a sub-array) from original array?

Answer (score 62):

```
<?php
$arr = array(0 => array("id"=>1,"name"=>"cat 1"),
             1 => array("id"=>2,"name"=>"cat 2"),
             2 => array("id"=>3,"name"=>"cat 1")
);
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($ar) {
   return ($ar['name'] == 'cat 1');
   //return ($ar['name'] == 'cat 1' AND $ar['id'] == '3');// you can add multiple conditions
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);

?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: This is a good solution if you want to search an array that is only one level deep, but this particular question was about searching recursively into a deep array ("the function has to be recursive to get down to the deepest level").

Answer (score 19):

Came back to post this update for anyone needing an optimisation tip on these answers, particulary John Kugelman's great answer up above.

His posted function work fine but I had to optimize this scenario for handling a 12 000 row resultset. The function was taking an eternal 8 secs to go through all records, waaaaaay too long.

I simply needed the function to STOP searching and return when match was found. Ie, if searching for a customer_id, we know we only have one in the resultset and once we find the customer_id in 
the multidimensional array, we want to return.

Here is the speed-optimised ( and much simplified ) version of this function, for anyone in need. Unlike other version, it can only handle only one depth of array, does not recurse and does away with merging multiple results.

```
// search array for specific key = value
public function searchSubArray(Array $array, $key, $value) {   
    foreach ($array as $subarray){  
        if (isset($subarray[$key]) && $subarray[$key] == $value)
          return $subarray;       
    } 
}
```

This brought down the the task to match the 12 000 records to a 1.5 secs. *Still very costly* but much more reasonable.

Comment: this one is faster than Jhon/Jared's answer (0.0009999275207519) vs (0.0020008087158203).. Well this test is specific to my case and environment.. Im sticking with this, thanks stefgosselin

Answer (score 16):

```
if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value)
```

A minor imporvement to the fast version.

Comment: Actually this prevents it from throwing warnings when the key is not set. Not so minor! -> +1'ed.

Comment: agreed, being able to actually glance through the php error log for major errors and not have it polluted with warnings is the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: This is not a complete solution and so is more of an "Attempt To Respond To Another Post" and "Not An Answer".

Answer (score 11):

Here is solution:

```
<?php
$students['e1003']['birthplace'] = ("Mandaluyong <br>");
$students['ter1003']['birthplace'] = ("San Juan <br>");
$students['fgg1003']['birthplace'] = ("Quezon City <br>");
$students['bdf1003']['birthplace'] = ("Manila <br>");

$key = array_search('Delata Jona', array_column($students, 'name'));
echo $key;  

?>
```

Answer (score 7):

Be careful of linear search algorithms (the above are linear) in multiple dimensional arrays as they have compounded complexity as its depth increases the number of iterations required to traverse the entire array. Eg:

```
array(
    [0] => array ([0] => something, [1] => something_else))
    ...
    [100] => array ([0] => something100, [1] => something_else100))
)
```

would take at the most 200 iterations to find what you are looking for (if the needle were at [100][1]), with a suitable algorithm.

Linear algorithms in this case perform at O(n) (order total number of elements in entire array), this is poor, a million entries (eg a 1000x100x10 array) would take on average 500,000 iterations to find the needle. Also what would happen if you decided to change the structure of your multidimensional array? And PHP would kick out a recursive algorithm if your depth was more than 100. Computer science can do better:

Where possible, always use objects instead of multiple dimensional arrays:

```
ArrayObject(
   MyObject(something, something_else))
   ...
   MyObject(something100, something_else100))
)
```

and apply a custom comparator interface and function to sort and find them:

```
interface Comparable {
   public function compareTo(Comparable $o);
}

class MyObject implements Comparable {
   public function compareTo(Comparable $o){
      ...
   }
}

function myComp(Comparable $a, Comparable $b){
    return $a->compareTo($b);
}
```

You can use `uasort()` to utilize a custom comparator, if you're feeling adventurous you should implement your own collections for your objects that can sort and manage them (I always extend ArrayObject to include a search function at the very least).

```
$arrayObj->uasort("myComp");
```

Once they are sorted (uasort is O(n log n), which is as good as it gets over arbitrary data), binary search can do the operation in O(log n) time, ie a million entries only takes ~20 iterations to search. As far as I am aware custom comparator binary search is not implemented in PHP (`array_search()` uses natural ordering which works on object references not their properties), you would have to implement this your self like I do.

This approach is more efficient (there is no longer a depth) and more importantly universal (assuming you enforce comparability using interfaces) since objects define how they are sorted, so you can recycle the code infinitely. Much better =)

Comment: This answer should be correct. Although the brute force search method will do it, this is much less resource intensive.

Comment: It should be noted that what you're suggesting only makes sense if you're searching the same array many times.  It takes far longer to go through the trouble of sorting it (O(n log n)) than it does to simply do a linear search for the value (O(n)).  But once it's sorted, sure, then a binary search would be faster.

Comment: I should also add that using objects instead of arrays may be a useful abstraction, but you could also do a binary search on an array if the array is sorted.  You don't need to use objects to sort an array or to do a binary search on it.

Comment: it would only take a single operation for needle @ [100][1] if anybody used correct implemented multithreading. start a thread from [0][0] forward, from [100][1] backward, from [50][1] backward and from [50][0] forward. you can basically reduce search time by adding more threads as long as your processor does not meltdown ^^

Answer (score 6):

```
$result = array_filter($arr, function ($var) {   
  $found = false;
  array_walk_recursive($var, function ($item, $key) use (&$found) {  
    $found = $found || $key == "name" && $item == "cat 1";
  });
  return $found;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

http://snipplr.com/view/51108/nested-array-search-by-value-or-key/

```
<?php

//PHP 5.3

function searchNestedArray(array $array, $search, $mode = 'value') {

    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $key => $value) {
        if ($search === ${${"mode"}})
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$data = array(
    array('abc', 'ddd'),
    'ccc',
    'bbb',
    array('aaa', array('yyy', 'mp' => 555))
);

var_dump(searchNestedArray($data, 555));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function in_multi_array($needle, $key, $haystack) 
{
    $in_multi_array = false;
    if (in_array($needle, $haystack))
    {
        $in_multi_array = true; 
    }else 
    {
       foreach( $haystack as $key1 => $val )
       {
           if(is_array($val)) 
           {
               if($this->in_multi_array($needle, $key, $val)) 
               {
                   $in_multi_array = true;
                   break;
               }
           }
        }
    }

    return $in_multi_array;
}
```

Comment: my case is different but got hint from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I needed something similar, but to search for multidimensional array by value... I took John example and wrote

```
function _search_array_by_value($array, $value) {
        $results = array();
        if (is_array($array)) {
            $found = array_search($value,$array);
            if ($found) {
                $results[] = $found;
            }
            foreach ($array as $subarray)
                $results = array_merge($results, $this->_search_array_by_value($subarray, $value));
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

I hope it helps somebody :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a revised function from the one that John K. posted... I need to grab only the specific key in the array and nothing above it.

```
function search_array ( $array, $key, $value )
{
    $results = array();

    if ( is_array($array) )
    {
        if ( $array[$key] == $value )
        {
            $results[] = $array;
        } else {
            foreach ($array as $subarray) 
                $results = array_merge( $results, $this->search_array($subarray, $key, $value) );
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

$arr = array(0 => array(id=>1,name=>"cat 1"),
       1 => array(id=>2,name=>"cat 2"),
       2 => array(id=>3,name=>"cat 1"));

print_r(search_array($arr, 'name', 'cat 1'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function findKey($tab, $key){
    foreach($tab as $k => $value){ 
        if($k==$key) return $value; 
        if(is_array($value)){ 
            $find = findKey($value, $key);
            if($find) return $find;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on this answer? Code only answers don't explain what you're actually doing.

Comment: Please update your question with the intent to educate.

Comment: This is functional for only find Key, This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is using php array functions if you know your key.

```
function search_array ( $array, $key, $value )
{
   return array_search($value,array_column($array,$key));
}
```

this return an index that you could find your desired data by this like below:

```
$arr = array(0 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => "cat 1"),
  1 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => "cat 2"),
  2 => array('id' => 3, 'name' => "cat 1")
);

echo json_encode($arr[search_array($arr,'name','cat 2')]);
```

this output will:

```
{"id":2,"name":"cat 2"}
```

Answer (score 1):

And another version that returns the key value from the array element in which the value is found (no recursion, optimized for speed):

```
// if the array is 
$arr['apples'] = array('id' => 1);
$arr['oranges'] = array('id' => 2);

//then 
print_r(search_array($arr, 'id', 2);
// returns Array ( [oranges] => Array ( [id] => 2 ) ) 
// instead of Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 ) )

// search array for specific key = value
function search_array($array, $key, $value) {
  $return = array();   
  foreach ($array as $k=>$subarray){  
    if (isset($subarray[$key]) && $subarray[$key] == $value) {
      $return[$k] = $subarray;
      return $return;
    } 
  }
}
```

Thanks to all who posted here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for array of keys this is good

```
function searchKeysInMultiDimensionalArray($array, $keys)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {
        $resultArray = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
        if (!empty($resultArray)) {
            $results[] = $resultArray;
        }

        foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, searchKeysInMultiDimensionalArray($subarray, $keys));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Keys will not overwrite because each set of key => values will be in separate array in resulting array.
If you don't want duplicate keys then use this one

```
function searchKeysInMultiDimensionalArray($array, $keys)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {
        $resultArray = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
        if (!empty($resultArray)) {
            foreach($resultArray as $key => $single) {

                $results[$key] = $single;
            }
        }

        foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, searchKeysInMultiDimensionalArray($subarray, $keys));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 functions: `array_search_key_value` which returns the array of keys to reach a key with a value in a multidimensional array, `array_extract_keys` which returns the value in a multidimensional array pointed to by an array of keys.

```
function array_search_key_value($array, $key, $value) {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return false;
    }

    return array_search_key_value_aux($array, $key, $value);
}

function array_search_key_value_aux($array, $key, $value, $path=null) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array) && $array[$key] === $value) {
        $path[]=$key;

        return $path;
    }

    foreach ($array as $k => $v ) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $path[]=$k;

            $p = array_search_key_value_aux($v, $key, $value, $path);

            if ($p !== false) {
                return $p;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function array_extract_keys($array, $key_list) {
    $v = $array;

    foreach ($key_list as $key) {
        if (!is_array($v) || !array_key_exists($key, $v))
            return false;

        $v = &$v[$key];
    } 
       
    return $v;
}
```

Here is a unitary test:

```
$test_array = array(
    'a' => array(
        'aa' => true,
        'ab' => array(
            'aaa' => array(
                'one' => 1,
                'two' => 2,
                'three' => 3,
                'four' => 4
            ),
            'four' => 4,
            'five' => 5,
        ),
        'six' => 6,
    ),
    'seven' => 7
);

$test_data = array(
    array('one', 1),
    array('two', 2),
    array('three', 3),
    array('four', 4),
    array('five', 5),
    array('six', 6),
    array('seven', 7),
    array('zero', 0),
    array('one', 0),
);

foreach ($test_data as $d) {
    $r = array_search_key_value($test_array, $d[0], $d[1]);

    echo $d[0] . ' => ' . $d[1] . ' ? ', $r ? implode('/', $r) . ' => ' . array_extract_keys($test_array, $r) : 'null', PHP_EOL;
}
```