# Check array for existence

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
$array = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [title] => sometext
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 47
            [title] => sometext
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 48
            [title] => sometext
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 49
            [title] => sometext
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50
            [title] => sometext
        )

)
```

We have an array and a variable:

```
$variable = 48; //some number
```

How do we check whether `$variable` exists in some arrays `['id']` inside `$array`?

Return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Python is *sooo* much more understandable: `48 in [18, 48]`. just saying ;)

Comment: come on ! Are you a developer ? So do a loop and find your value ! Even if there is a built in function it has to loop through your object. Is it homework ?

Comment: This is a multidimensional array, not just a regular one.

Comment: look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function myCheck($array, $variable)
    foreach($array as $subArray) {
        if($subArray['id'] == $variable) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this function:

```
function check_array() {
  foreach ($array as $ar) {
    if ($ar['id'] == $variable)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This answer was added like 5 minutes after the first answers, and it's identical... how did it get up-voted over the others?

Comment: @xil3, When I browse through the questions I usually open several in tabs at once and then go through them.  Just b/c my answer was later doesn't mean it was copied.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)?  It returns the key value if found, or false if not found.