# Multidimensional array search using php

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10184
            [meta_tags] => tag1,tag2

        )
)
```

How do i search by keyword (example, `tag1`) in an array.

Thank u.

Comment: ... and then take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php/1019534#1019534).

Answer (score 1):

```
function ($haystack, $tag) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($tag, explode(',', $value['meta_tags']) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a recursive function since arrays don't have the same dimensions.

Please, refer to [that post](http://greengaloshes.cc/2007/04/recursive-multidimensional-array-search-in-php/) that features a recursive function really useful.