# Search multidimensional array by specific key and print the value php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to print array. All code working fine with foreach loop. But I'm trying to print with associated keys. Is it possible?

Example:  `key['user_id']` this will print all `user_id` from array. is it possible? please help me thanks

```
Array
(
    [Post1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => hi
    )
    [Post2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 2
            )
    )
    [Post3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user_name] => 1
            )
    )
)
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
foreach($post as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $print => $key) {
        if (is_array($key)){
            foreach($key as $print2 => $key2) {
                echo "<br>".$key2;
            }
        }else{
            echo "<br>".$key;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Given example is not clear enough ?

Comment: Use `print_r` or `var_dump()`.

Comment: @Shakti Singh My array display all records from array. I don't want to print whole array. I just want to print particular data from array. suppose I want to print `username and userid' form array. is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: What should the output of the above example look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can `print_r` to achive the same results you want with your triple for each.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to print array. All code working fine with foreach loop. But I'm trying to print with associated keys. Is it possible?

You can easily use recursion for such a problem. You can use something along the lines of:

```
function printValuesByKey($array, $key) {
    if (!is_array($array)) return;
    if (isset($array[$key])) 
        echo $key .': '. $array[$key] .'<br>';
    else
        foreach ($array as $v)
            printValuesByKey($v, $key);
}
```

In your example:

```
printValuesByKey($array, 'user_id');
```

[will](http://ideone.com/o6Dfwi) print:

```
user_id: 1
user_id: 2
```