# php, efficient way to determine if this value is in my array

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find values in multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811908/find-values-in-multidimensional-arrays)

This is my array, it contains an array of key value pairs.

```
[
   {
    valueA: 0,
    valueB: 0,
    day: "2010-04-09"
   },
   {
    valueA: 0,
    valueB: 0,
    day: "2010-04-10"
   }
]
```

I want to check if a certain value is at key "day" in any index (and if so, modify the values in that node)

is there an efficient way to do this with the `in_array` method?

otherwise I guess I would do it with a nested for loop

Comment: foreach($array as $index=>$object){ if($object->day==$day){return $index; }}  -- something like this?

Comment: Loop over it, or have PHP loop over it using `array_filter`, `array_walk`, etc.

Comment: @SalmanA my production server is using php 5.2.2

Comment: @CQM upgrade your server .....

Comment: @Baba it is not my server, better answer?

Comment: @CQM: better answer is to loop over the array. `array_filter` should work though but without those fancy callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop only once and set date as key

```
$hash = array();
foreach ( $array as $v ) {
    $hash[$v['day']][] = $v;
}
```

Now you can use `isset` which is `O(1)` rather than `O(n)`  all the time

```
if (isset($hash['2010-04-10'])) {
    echo "Here";
}
```

Comment: yeah, this is the route I am going now kind of. Mainly just the part about setting date as a key too. Thanks for your contributions

Answer (score 1):

Not with the `in_array` function, but you can use `array_filter`:

```
// assuming $myarray = Array(......);
if( $found = array_filter($myarray,function($a) {return $a['day'] == '2010-04-10';})) {
    // you can now do something with the $found array
}
```

EDIT: Just saw your comment about using PHP 5.2.2 - this version doesn't support anonymous functions, so you will need this:

```
if( $found = array_filter($myarray,create_function('$a','return $a["day"] == "2010-04-10";')))
```

Comment: okay, so in php 5.2.2 I can't pass any variables into `create_function` ?

Comment: Nope, except maybe with `global`. You'd be better off upgrading anyway, since PHP 5.5 is coming out.

Comment: your PHP version was not in your question ......

Answer (score 0):

I would use array_map instead.  This will allow you to modify the array when the keys match.  array_filter just allows population of an array.

If you create a new method (using 5.2 and create_function) you can specify your logic in it.  Then, pass that into the array_map method to get your new, processed array.

In my example below, I'm checking to see if the 'day' of the variable is '2010-04-10' - and if so, changing valueA of that particular array to 1.

```
$processArrayFunction = create_function('$a',
                                        'if ($a["day"] == "2010-04-10") {
                                            $a["valueA"] = 1;
                                        }
                                        return $a;
                                        ');

$newArray = array_map($processArrayFunction, $sourceArray);
```

Comment: I still feel like I will be needing to pass variables into the create_function method. What if my keys are dynamically generated

Comment: Since the second parameter of create_function() is a string, you could splice in any variable you'd want when you defined that function.  Or, you could define create_function() to have two parameters in the first string (the second being your variable)... and then pass that after $sourceArray.  If this doesn't make sense, please let me know and I'll generate a code sample.