# Searching specific value in array

Tags: php

I have an array, and i want to find all values where `correct => true`:

```
   $quiz_array = array (
            'question1' => array (
                        'q1a1' => array (
                                  'correct' => FALSE,
                                  'answer' => 'false answer1'
                        ),
                        'q1a2' => array (
                                  'correct' => FALSE,
                                  'answer' => 'false answer2'
                        ),
                        'q1a3' => array (
                                  'correct' => FALSE,
                                  'answer' => 'false answer3'
                        ),                  
                        'q1a4' => array (
                                  'correct' => TRUE,
                                  'answer' => 'correct answer'
                        )
            )
    );
```

I want to do a search, where it would return `q1a4` in this case, because `correct => TRUE`. I trid using `in_array` and `array_search` but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find values in multidimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811908/find-values-in-multidimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer,

```
foreach($quiz_array as $key=> $value) {
  foreach($quiz_array[$key] as $key=> $value) {
    if( $value["correct"] ) {
        echo $key ."<br>";  
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($quiz_array as $key => $value) {
 if (strpos($value, '<name of value you want to search>') !== false) {
    $new_key = $key;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$correctAnswers = array();
foreach ($quiz_array as $question => $answers) {
  $correctAnswers[$question] = array_filter($answers, function($v) { 
    return $v['correct']; 
  });
}
var_dump($correctAnswers); // array('question1' => array('q1a4' => array('correct' => true, 'answer' => 'correct answer')));
```

If you want to return **just** the correct answers `key` (eg. `q1a41`) you could do:

```
$correctAnswers = array();
foreach ($quiz_array as $question => $answers) {
  foreach ($answers as $k => $a) {
    if ($a['correct']) { 
      $correctAnswers[$question] = $k;
    }
  }
}
var_dump($correctAnswers); // array('question1' => 'q1a4');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function correct($array) {
    return $array('correct');
}

$results= array();
foreach($quiz_array as $key => $value) {
    $correct= array_filter($value, 'correct');
    $results[$key]= $correct;
}

print_r($results);
```