# how can i get multidimensional array values using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I want to use a multidimensional array in different functions.so i am making it as a global variable(array).i created a multidimensional array and made it as global to access in different function.now how can i get the values from it using foreach loop?
here is my code

```
$test=array(
       array(
        "input1"=>"v1",
        "input2"=>"v2"),
        array(
         "input3"=>"v3",
         "input4"=>"v4")
      );

class testing
{
  function testp()
  {
    global $test;
    foreach($test as $key => $value)
    {
      echo $value;
    }
    var_dump($test);
    echo is_array($test);
  }
}

$obj = new testing();
$obj->testp();
```

i used is_array and `var_dump` to confirm whether its an array.
all are fine
and its shwoing **Error suppression ignored**. now how can i get the values from it?

Comment: Indent that horrible code :)

Comment: Possible duplicates for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811908/find-values-in-multidimensional-arrays

Comment: Although not what you're asking for (sashkello covered that just fine) I highly recommend you get rid of the use of global and instead 'set' the array using a setter object method: function setData( array $data ) { $this->_data = $data; } .. you'll realize why once the app get bigger and your code is ridden with globals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is array of arrays, what works for top order array, works further as well:

```
foreach($test as $key => $value)
{
   foreach($value as $k => $v){
      echo $v;
   }
}
```

This will echo your values v1, v2, v3, v4 one after another.

Comment: Fine.Now how can i get values upto v3 not v4?

Comment: @raj, just make a counter which will break out of loop on 3.

Answer (score 1):

More general answer:

```
public function visitArray($test)
{
  foreach($test as $key=>$value)
  {
    if(is_array($value))
    {
      visitArray($value);
    }
    else
    {
      echo $value;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Edit

Don't know why you're looping over keys and values, if key isn't took into account

Answer (score 1):

More easy & simple way to access array values within a array.

```
foreach($test as $array_value){

    if(is_array($array_value)) {
        foreach ($array_value as $value) {
             echo $value.'<br>';
        }
      }
    }
```