# Official way to find an element in a php bidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

Looking at the code above...

```
$Array = array(array("name"=>"Mickey","type"=>"mouse"),array("name"=>"Donald","type"=>"duck"),array("name"=>"Little Helper","type"=>"eniac"));
$search = "Donald";
foreach($Array as $Item){
    if($Item["name"]==$search) $MyItem = $Item;
}
echo('The item named "'.$search.'" is '.$MyItem["type"]);
```

... I have the feeling that there is an array function or a better way to find an item inside a bidimensional array. These arrays are like a table. Maybe setting the keys as the index unique values (in this case, the name), but I don't know how to do either.

Comment: there is no official way. php has single dimensional arrays and offers a large number of functions to deal with 1 dimensional arrays. the fact that you can embed arrays in arrays doesn't change the fact that php's functions are all geared to single dimensional arrays.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811908/find-values-in-multidimensional-arrays

Comment: I'm only aware of one function specifically for dealing with multidimensional arrays: [array_multisort](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

Comment: @MarcB - while most individual functions are targeted at single dimensional arrays, there are a couple of exceptions like the new array_column()

Comment: @djot: I did a lot o searches and did't find it, maybe stack needs a better searcher...

Comment: @MarcB: not sure about this, conceptually speaking. Any space is generated by a certain number of dimensions, one by one. Php is only following mathematics.

Comment: @GustavoPinent: truu, but php arrays can't be done with `$arr[1,2]` or whatever. You get one key in an array, and that's your 1 dimension. The fact that `$arr[1][2]` works is irrelevant. that's two separate 1 dimensional arrays, orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the new [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function in PHP 5.5

```
$Array = array(array("name"=>"Mickey","type"=>"mouse"),array("name"=>"Donald","type"=>"duck"),array("name"=>"Little Helper","type"=>"eniac"));
$search = "Donald";

$key = array_search(
    $search,
    array_column($Array,'name')
);
if($key !== false) {
    $MyItem = $Array[$key];
    echo('The item named "'.$search.'" is '.$MyItem["type"]);
}
```

Comment: I did a proposal. I think will be the "official" solution because came from php producers. Also I suggest you to put a previous version temp code, I don't have any server with this version running, maybe is not very popular so far.

Comment: PHP 5.5 is still only running on about 1.3% of web sites according to w3techs.com, but growing slowly in popularity

Comment: @MarkBaker: Anyway, spread the wor(l)d. I try to popularise `array_column` wherever I can ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you can recompose the array as:

```
array("Mickey"=>"mouse","Donald"=>"duck","Little Helper"=>"eniac");
```

or

```
array("Mickey"=>array("name"=>"mouse"),"Donald"=>array("name"=>"duck"),"Little Helper"=>array("name"=>"eniac"));
```

and just return by key

Answer (score 0):

Works for this case:

```
echo array_column($Array, 'type', 'name')[$search];
```

Or with check:

```
$names = array_column($Array, 'type', 'name');
echo isset($names[$search]) ? $names[$search] : 'not found';
```

To convert to `name` => `type` use:

```
$Array = array_column($Array, 'type', 'name');
```

Then after you can just use `$Array[$search]`.

Comment: @GustavoPinent: The first example with the `[$search]` nomenclature works as of PHP 5.4.0.  `array_column()` is only available in PHP > 5.5.0. So your way is it for your version.

Comment: Also, in 5.3.x (version I work) array_function(args)[key] doesn't works, I got to doit in two steps Array = array_function(args) and than Array[key]. I'm thinking about an upgrade...