# Find users likes a page : Best method?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
 $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes");
 foreach($likes['data'] as $page_likes) {
    if($page_likes['id'] == "someid") {

    }
  }
```

Is there any simple way to find it instead of looping those hundreds, thousands likes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best method (to answer questions like this): **Read documentation …!**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes:

> “You can check if a User likes a specific page by issuing an HTTP GET to /PROFILE_ID/likes/PAGE_ID. […] This will return, in the data array, an object with the following fields if the user is connected to the page: […] If the user is not connected to the page, the data array will be empty.”

Answer (score 0):

array_map or array_walk might be more efficient, but it depends on what you want to do with the data...

Comment: From this loop, If the page id is liked, i will end the loop and display some additional content. That is it.