# How to load specific elements from array?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

We put a MySQL table data in an array that named $row1. Now, we want to echo some rows only from this array. For example :

```
While ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo $row1['name'];
}
```

(But where the id is equal 5)

How we can do this?

Comment: if($row1['id'] == 5) { echo $row1['name'] ; }

Comment: Why didn't you just `SELECT` the rows where the `id = 5`?

Comment: I find it a little short-sighted to select a number or rows and put them in a variable named row1.

Comment: Also don't use the `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your SQL statement, add this to the end: `WHERE id = 5`, if you already have a `WHERE` clause, add `AND id = 5`

Alternately...

```
if ($row1['id'] == 5)
{
   echo $row1['name'];
}
```

Post all your code..we can make this experience less painful for you.

Comment: No. We want to create a menu by <ul> and <li>. Submenus have an ID that define which submenu is under which mainmenu. We placed the submenu MySQL table in an array. Now we need to load just some elements from array. how we can do this?

Comment: You're going to have to give more info on your database design and what not, im not a magician.  Can't help you if you don't explain what you need clearly.

Comment: There is a table with 2 columns, name and id (ID is not primary and unique).
name------ID
John------5
Jackie----4
Sarah-----5
marshal---4
bigman----3

Now, we fetch this table to an array. In a while loop, we need PHP just load and show the names that in array have ID #5.

Comment: so make another column with "nav_parent" and if ($row1['nav_parent']) echo it

Comment: There is a table with 2 columns, name and id (ID is not primary and unique). name------ID John------5 Jackie----4 Sarah-----5 marshal---4 bigman----3 Now, we fetch this table to an array. In a while loop, we need PHP just load and show the names that in array have ID #5.