# Get the sub array in a bidimensional array having a particular key/value pair

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, keyvaluepair, sub-array

I have a large PHP array, similar to:

```
$list = array(
    array(
        'id'     = '3243'
        'link'   = 'fruits'
        'lev'    = '1'
    ),
    array(
        'id'     = '6546'
        'link'   = 'apple'
        'lev'    = '2'
    ),
    array(
        'id'     = '9348'
        'link'   = 'orange'
        'lev'    = '2'
    )
)
```

I want to get the sub-array which contains a particular `id`.

Currently I use the following code:

```
$id = '3243'
foreach ($list as $link) {
    if (in_array($id, $link)) {
        $result = $link;
    }
}
```

It works but I hope there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Not really, no - although it seems like `in_array` would be better replaced with `$link['id'] == $id`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: @ke20 the answers there are mostly for multidimensional arrays, the solutions here are simpler somewhat (since OP's array is only bidimensional).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can

- write `$link['id']==$id` instead of `in_array($id, $link)` whitch will be less expensive.
- add a `break;` instruction after `$result = $link;` to avoid useless loops

Comment: This page _could_ be use to close future duplicates but sadly the accepted answer isn't very clean / readable.   Perhaps improve this answer with a complete code block and keep the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

While this answer wouldn't have worked when the question was asked, there's quite an easy way to solve this dilemma now.

You can do the following in PHP 5.5:

```
$newList = array_combine(array_column($list,'id'),$list);
```

And the following will then be true:

```
$newList[3243] = array(
                         'id'   = '3243';
                         'link' = 'fruits'; etc...
```

Comment: No, no, no, wait.  Don't do this.  Rather, go to `array_column()` in the php manual and read about its 3rd parameter.  `array_combine()` should not be called.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way in PHP 5.4 and above is a combination of [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and the [`use` language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165) in its callback function:

```
function subarray_element($arr, $id_key, $id_val = NULL) {
  return current(array_filter(
    $arr,
    function ($subarr) use($id_key, $id_val) {
      if(array_key_exists($id_key, $subarr))
        return $subarr[$id_key] == $id_val;
    }
  ));
}
var_export(subarray_element($list, 'id', '3243')); // returns:
// array (
//   'id' => '9348',
//   'link' => 'orange',
//   'lev' => '2',
// )
```

[`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) just returns the first element of the filtered array.
  A few more [online 3v4l examples of getting different sub-arrays](https://3v4l.org/XioRa) from OP's `$list`.