# Remove an Item from cart session multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, session, cart

Im working on Add to cart module, the session array that i am finally getting is something like this:

```
    Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Array
                        (
                            [item_name] => burger
                            [item_price] => 5
                            [item_qty] => 3
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Array
                        (
                            [item_name] => pizza
                            [item_price] => 15
                            [item_qty] => 2
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Array
                        (
                            [item_name] => french fries
                            [item_price] => 8
                            [item_qty] => 5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to remove an item from this array, say the item with name "pizza". How can i do it??

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function rem_from_array(&$session_array, $name)
{
  foreach($session_array as $key=>$elem)
    if($elem['item']['item_name']==$name)
    {
      unset($session_array[$key]);

      return;
    }
}
```

then you should just execute the following code:

```
rem_from_array($_SESSION['cart'], 'pizza');
```