# Get array part by multi-dimensional array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [fall] => Array
        (
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Test
                    [Description] => Test description
                    [Slug] => tester
                )

            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => fall_1.jpg
                    [1] => fall_2.jpg
                    [2] => fall_3.jpg
                    [3] => fall_4.jpg
                )

        )

    [spring] => Array
        (
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => spring_1.jpg
                    [1] => spring_2.jpg
                    [2] => spring_3.jpg
                    [3] => spring_4.jpg
                    [4] => spring_5.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

What I'm looking to do is get the `fall` array if both `info` exists and `Slug` is equal to `tester`. I researched and saw [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php) but mine is dependent on a sub-array being available -- would it be the same idea?

As an example, if `tester` was the only param given, I'd want the `fall` array to be returned.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I'd want to be able to return the array position that has the slug if the slug is the only param given"

Comment: If the slug `tester` was given, I'd want the `fall` array to be returned.

Comment: That's exactly what my answer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily just do

```
if (isset($array['fall']['info']['Slug']) && $array['fall']['info']['Slug'] == 'tester') {
    return $array['fall'];
}
```

Comment: Hi, appreciate the answer. To clarify, I'd want to be able to return the array position that has the slug if the slug is the only param given (going to be doing this from a `$_GET` param. Thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain exactly what you want because it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as the one you linked.

```
if(is_array($your_array_name['fall']['info']) && $your_array_name['fall']['info']['Slug'] == 'tester') {
  // Execute code here...
}
```