# How check array element exist in two-dimessional array in php

Tags: php

I have an array that is like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 1
        [product_name] => T-Shirts
        [quantity] => 2
        [price] => 300
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 2
        [product_name] => Red Shirt
        [quantity] => 4
        [price] => 200
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 3
        [product_name] => Cap
        [quantity] => 2
        [price] => 50
    )

)
```

I want to check whether the product_id exist or not. I tried to in_array but did not get any result.

Is there any built-in function to check it without putting the array in loop.

Comment: there's a lot of different methods for this if you just search for it... [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1019076/623952) seems to have a fair amount of upvotes even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by gloomy.penguin, you could use array_filter

```
<?php
$a = Array
(
0 => Array
    (
        "product_id" => 1,
        "product_name" => "T-Shirts",
        "quantity" => 2,
        "price" => 300,
    ),

1 => Array
    (
        "product_id" => 2,
        "product_name" => "Red Shirt",
        "quantity" => 4,
        "price" => 200,
    ),

2 => Array
    (
        "product_id" => 3,
        "product_name" => "Cap",
        "quantity" => 2,
        "price" => 50,
    ),

);

$result = array_filter($a, function($var) {
    if ($var['product_id'] == 3) return true;
});

if (empty($result)) echo "Not found";
else echo "Found";

echo var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through every product:

```
foreach($array as $product) {
    if(isset($product['product_id']))
        // do something
}
```

I don't think there's a built-in function to handle this.

Comment: there's array_filter()