# PHP search line in array

Tags: php, arrays, search, line

i have a result on mysql where i have a lot of lines and a lot of columns. i need to *echo* a specific line that i don't know.

Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 195
            [id_privilegios] => 195
            [1] => 206
            [id_usuario] => 206
            [2] => 10
            [id_menu] => 10
            [3] => S
            [consultar] => S
            [4] => 
            [inserir] => 
            [5] => S
            [alterar] => S
            [6] => 
            [excluir] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 194
            [id_privilegios] => 194
            [1] => 206
            [id_usuario] => 206
            [2] => 9
            [id_menu] => 9
            [3] => S
            [consultar] => S
            [4] => S
            [inserir] => S
            [5] => S
            [alterar] => S
            [6] => S
            [excluir] => S
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 193
            [id_privilegios] => 193
            [1] => 206
            [id_usuario] => 206
            [2] => 1
            [id_menu] => 1
            [3] => S
            [consultar] => S
            [4] => S
            [inserir] => S
            [5] => S
            [alterar] => S
            [6] => S
            [excluir] => S
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 224
            [id_privilegios] => 224
            [1] => 206
            [id_usuario] => 206
            [2] => 56
            [id_menu] => 56
            [3] => S
            [consultar] => S
            [4] => S
            [inserir] => S
            [5] => S
            [alterar] => S
            [6] => 
            [excluir] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 223
            [id_privilegios] => 223
            [1] => 206
            [id_usuario] => 206
            [2] => 52
            [id_menu] => 52
            [3] => S
            [consultar] => S
            [4] => S
            [inserir] => S
            [5] => S
            [alterar] => S
            [6] => S
            [excluir] => S
        )

)
```

i have this array for example and i want to show the value of "consultar" column where id_menu = 7

how i can echo this ?

thanks

Comment: By iterating through the array and checking the `['id_menu']` key?

Comment: Make your array output more readable

Comment: You can get a formatted output by wrapping the `print_r()` statement in `<pre>` tags like so: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($yourArray, TRUE).'</pre>';`.

Comment: This has been answered before, have a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1019126/407697

Comment: You write a function that identifies the index of the `array` where `array[index]['id_menu'] === 7` and then you return `array[index]['consultar']`

Comment: Would it make more sense to change your query so you only got the result where the id_menu value matches what you want?  What you are doing may make sense for your situation, but it's often best to query so your result data better matches up with your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one item, you'll have to iterate through and find the matching element, if more than one item, one way is to use array_filter to filter out all the matching array elements.

```
function myFilter( $row) {
   return ($row['id_menu'] == 7);
}

$matches = array_filter($my_array, "myFilter");
foreach ($matches as $element) {
   echo "Menu Id: {$element['id_menu']} Consultar: {$element['consultar']}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `array_filter` in conjunction with `array_map`.

```
$result = array_map(
    function ($v) {
        return $v['consultar'];
    },
    array_filter($array, function ($v) {
        return $v['id_menu'] == 7;
    })
);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: it is missing an ")"

i change to array_filter($array, function ($v)) { but it doesnt work "/

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Comment: Update your PHP version to 5.3+

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    if(isset($arr[$key]["id_menu"]) && $arr[$key]["id_menu"] == 7){
         echo $arr[$key]["consultar"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()