# PHP Insert array into multidimensional array by using an array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got arrays like this build upon data from a database representing single pages of a cms:

```
    $page =

            Array
        (
            [title] => mein produkt
            [NavID] => 200
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 200
                )

        )
```

And I need to put that into an other multidimensional array like this representing the sitemap:

```
$map =

    Array
    (
        [NavID] => 0
        [0] => Array
            (
                [childs] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => home
                                [NavID] => 1
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => impressum
                                [NavID] => 2
                                [childs] => Array
                                    (
                                        [100] => Array
                                            (
                                                [title] => startseite
                                                [NavID] => 100
                                                [parents] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => 0
                                                        [1] => 2
                                                        [2] => 100
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => produkte
                                [NavID] => 3
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

As you see, I got the structure of the array as the array value on `parents`.

So what I would do by hand is putting this like:

```
$map[0]['childs'][3]['childs'][200] = $page;
```

Put how can I select the multidimensional array with my array value `$page['parents']`?

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Use [array_keys()](http://php.net/array_keys) to access the inter arrays keys more at

Comment: read this like:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `$page['parents'][KEY]` as keys when accessing `$map` values that way :

```
$map[$page['parents'][0]]['childs'][$page['parents'][1]]['childs'][$page['parents'][2]] = $page;
```

As your tree grows, I'd really suggest to shorten it with a direct variable :

```
$par = $page['parents'];
$map[$par[0]]['childs'][$par[1]]['childs'][$par[2]] = $page;
```

To dynamically go to the correct node, just loop over your parents using references :

```
$tmp = &$map;
$first = true;
foreach ($page['parents'] as $parent) {
  if ($first) { // Quick workaround to skip the first node without 'childs' key
    $tmp = &$tmp[$parent];
    $first = false;
    continue;
  }
  $tmp = &$tmp['childs'][$parent];
}
$tmp = $page;
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But I don't know now deep the page is, so maybe there are six parent elements. I know I can use array_count to determine how many I got. But then again, how can I put this in one line like your answer?

Comment: What I need is to create this pointer "$map[$par[0]]['childs'][$par[1]]['childs'][$par[2]]" programmatically.

Comment: @da.eXecutoR Updated my answer to use references / pointers as you want.

Comment: I had to make a small mod to get it working:

$tmp = &$map;
$first = true;
foreach ($page['parents'] as $parent) {
  if ($first) { // Quick workaround to skip the first node without childs
    $first = false;
    $tmp = &$tmp[$parent];
    continue;
  }
  $tmp = &$tmp['childs'][$parent];
}
$tmp = $page;

Thank you very much mate! Made my day!