# Accessing object property by variable in php

Tags: php, object

Objectives:
I am trying to read certain parts of **any** json file by letting the user input the desired properties.

Say I have an object that looks like this:

```
"adverts": [
    {
    "id": "33655628",
    "companyInfo": {
            "companyName": "Company A",
            "homepage": "http://companya.com",
            "companyText": null
    },
    ...
]
```

I want to access the properties by assigning the property name or "path" by a variable.
Accessing the first level ($item->$_id) works fine but how do I access a nested property *companyName* directly with by a variable such as

```
 $_name = "companyInfo->companyName";
```

Ex:

```
$_repeat = "adverts";
$_id = "id";
$_name = ??????

foreach($data->$_repeat as $item){
    var_dump($item->$_id);
    var_dump($item->$_name);
}
```

EDIT:
As clarification: I want this to be universal for **any** JSON object!

PRELIMINARY SOLUTION:
I got the desired results by looping as suggested by @Carlos:

```
$_title_a = explode(".",$_title);
$current = $document;
foreach($_title_a as $a){
    $current = $current->$a;
}
var_dump($current);
```

If someone has a better suggestion, I would be glad to hear it. Thanks everybody!

Comment: You probably need to parse your string and loop over the components. Or use something like `eval`...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have json data with you..you can use below code..

```
$obj= json_decode($yourJsonData);
print_r($obj);

foreach ($obj as $key => $value) { 
    $companyinfo = $value['companyInfo']['companyName'];
}
```

In foreach loop you will get require key and values..this is just a example for you..

Comment: I don't want to print the whole json object. The question was "But how do I access a nested property companyName directly with by a variable"

Comment: @Holle..updated answer as per your requirement..please have a look

Comment: To access the nested property of json you should know about the depth..so that based on that depth you can do loop and fetch that data or you should know about index of that particular data...

Comment: So you're saying is not possible to assign a "multidepth" variable?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you exactly need this?

All you have to do is:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonString, true);

echo $jsonData['adverts'][0]['companyInfo']['companyName'];

//or

foreach($jsonData['adverts'] as $advert){
    echo $advert['companyInfo']['companyName'];
}
```

Comment: Yes but the property names and object "depth" is not known, thus the need for variables.

Comment: @Holle take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: Thanks @Carlos! I read that answer but I was hoping for a simpler solution which doesn't involve looping/searching since I "just" need to somehow make this: $item->"companyInfo->companyName" into this $item->companyInfo->companyName

Comment: It will require you to do a search loop, even if you're working whith objects, since your json is structured as "various companies". If you dont want it, you'll have to assume its aways looking in the first row (index 0 for example)

Comment: I updated my question with a priliminary solution with looping. Thanks