# x and y key value pair must match, find in array

Tags: php, arrays

```
array (size=9)
 0 => 
  array (size=2)
   'x' => int 1
   'y' => int 4
  1 => 
 array (size=2)
  'x' => int 1
  'y' => int 5
  2 => 
 array (size=2)
  'x' => int 1
  'y' => int 6
  3 => 
 array (size=2)
  'x' => int 1
  'y' => int 7
 4 => 
array (size=2)
  'x' => int 1
  'y' => int 8
 5 => 
 array (size=2)
  'x' => int 4
  'y' => int 9
 6 => 
array (size=2)
  'x' => int 5
  'y' => int 9
 7 => 
array (size=2)
  'x' => int 6
  'y' => int 9
 8 => 
 array (size=2)
  'x' => int 7
  'y' => int 9
```

The above is an array of x and y coordinates where I have battle ships plotted, I want to search the array and return true when the x,y I send matches the x,y pair of arrays.  I can do it if I choose just x on it's own, or y on it's own, but having trouble searching both x and y.

```
function searcharray($value, $key, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $val) {
        //echo $val[$key];
        if ($val[$key] == $value) {
            return TRUE;
            //$val[$key];
        }
    }
    return null;
 }

$array;
// both these must match    

$key='y';
$value=9;
$key2='x';
Varlue2='5';


$result = searcharray($value,$key,$array);

echo $result;
```

Comment: This may be help full for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate an intersection of 2 arrays. If they have a common element, the result would be `true`, otherwise `false`. However, because you are comparing multidimensional arrays, you need to use custom function for comparison thus the intersection should be calculated using [`array_uintersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php):

```
$haystack = [['x'=>'1','y'=>'1'],['x'=>'2','y'=>'1']];
$search = [['x'=>'1','y'=>'1']]; // NOTE: this must be a multidimensional array

$result = (bool)array_uintersect($haystack, $search, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a['x'].$a['y'], $b['x'].$b['y']);
});
```

[TEST](https://eval.in/316026)

Comment: Thanks, this works and I think it's a very elegant solution for how I think anyway.  Not even come across array_unitersect() before

Comment: I'm having trouble making strcasecmp() work if my array is an integer.  If I make it a string is works, as x and y are integers it's hard to keep forcing them to strings in one case not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: That is strange because with the `.` concatenation it should always be comparing strings, even if the originals are integers. Here is another [test](https://eval.in/316456). Could you try to modify the test so that it fails as in your case?

Comment: realised as it's a multidemsional array, I need to specify the search like this $search = array(array('x'=>'2','y'=>'6'));  instead of $search = array('x'=>'2','y'=>'6');  it was catching anything starting with x=1 then nothing else

Comment: Correct! The two arrays must have the same structure. I should have highlighted it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isArrayEntrySet($array, $x, $y) {
    return (boolean) count(
        array_filter(
            $myArray,
            function ($value) use ($x $y) {
                return $value['x'] == $x && $value['y'] == $y;
            }
        )
    ) > 0;
}

$x = 9;
$y = 5;
if (isArrayEntrySet($array, $x, $y)) {
    echo 'BANG!!!';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's several ways of achieving what you want, here's a small function to help you do that:

```
function identical_values( $arrayA , $arrayB ) {
    sort( $arrayA );
    sort( $arrayB );
    return $arrayA === $arrayB;
}
```

Basically we first sort both arrays and then compare if they are equal `===`
Equal arrays will return `TRUE` while different return `FALSE`.

---

Example:

```
$array1 = array("x" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("x" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");

if(identical_values( $array1 , $array2 )){
echo "arrays are equal";
}
```

---

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/fnms1X)

Comment: The code does exactly what the OP wants. Care to comment the down vote ?