# Select a SubArray if today date is between 2 keys value

Tags: php, arrays, date, array-filter

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'first element',
        'start' => '30/04/2015',
        'end' => '30/06/2015'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'second element',
        'start' => '01/07/2015',
        'end' => '30/09/2015'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'fourth element',
        'start' => '01/10/2015',
        'end' => '15/12/2015'
        )
);
```

I need to select one array subarray (item) based on the today date.
today date must be between start date and end date keys.

In the end I would like to have this:

```
$selected_subarray = array (
        'name' => 'first element',
        'start' => '30/04/2015',
        'end' => '30/06/2015'
    )
```

I use to check between two dates like this:

```
function check_if_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $today_date)
{
  $start_d = strtotime($start_date);
  $end_d = strtotime($end_date);
  $today_d = strtotime($today_date);
  return (($today_d >= $start_d) && ($today_d <= $end_d));
}
```

I tryed to follow suggestions from this question [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

but if I'm able to filter for a key = value, I'm not able to do the same using the "check_if_in_range" function.

Comment: How did you use `check_if_in_range`?

Comment: as Glavić has pointed out in the answer I've pick my error was on date format. I was comparing '30/06/2015' to date('d/m/Y') in the check_if_in_range function, and it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do know that `30/06/2015` is invalid date, and `strtotime()` will return `false`? See [here](https://eval.in/317960). Format `mm/dd/yyyy` is an American month, day and year. So your format is non-standard.

Best way is to convert it to standard format, and then use `strtotime()`<sup>[example](https://eval.in/318117)</sup> or just use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`<sup>[example](https://eval.in/318120)</sup>.

After you learn how formating and converting dates works, then you can just do simple foreach loop, and break on first found result. Here is a little [demo](https://eval.in/318125).

Answer (score -1):

Try something like the following

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(check_in_range($value['start'], $value['end'], $today_date)) {
        $selected_subarray = $value;
    }
}
```