# Php multidimensional array get value from arrays with different keys

Tags: php

I need help. I have an array:

```
$A = 
    array(
        "0" =>
            array(
                "1" => array('name' => '1234', 'value' => '1'),
                "2" => array('name' => '5678', 'value' => '8')
            ),
        "1" =>
            array(
                "1" => array('name' => '5678', 'value' => '5')
            )
    );
```

How can I get the `value` (in foreach loop) from arrays if array key `name` value is `5678`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
foreach ($A as $B) {
 foreach ($B as $C) {
    if ($C['name'] == '5678') {
       echo $C['value'].'<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach ($A as $array_item) {
  foreach ($array_item as $inner_array) {
      if ($inner_array['name'] == '5678') {
          var_dump($inner_array['value']);
      }   
  }   
}
```