# Checking to see if a variable exists in an array with in_array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using in_array to see if $appid is contained in the variable $r. Here is my print_r of the array $r (the appids in the array are always changing):

```
$array = array(0 =>
    array(0 => 356050, 'appid' => 356050),
    1 => array(0 => 338040, ' appid' => 338040),
    2 => array(0 => 263920, 'appid' => 263920),
    3 => array(0 => 411740, 'appid' => 411740)
);
```

$appid is equal 263920 which is contained in $r array, yet despite the criteria being met 'it works' is not being echoed. Any help would be appreciated as I don't understand what's flawed about my php statement.

```
if (in_array($appid, $r)) {
echo 'it works'; // criteria met
}
```

Comment: can you show the proper array and not the `print_r` ?? and I dont think your array is complete, where is the element under index 4 ??

Comment: Your array is multi-dimensional. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Your array is a multidimensional array, this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array containing arrays. The function in_array() looks at the content of the outer array, without recursing into inner arrays. It would find something if you did

```
if (in_array(array(0 => $appid, 'appid' => $appid), $r) { 
    echo 'It works'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old way, but this will work.
since your input is a multidimensional array, you need to loop through the array and search if the value is in array.

```
<?php
$array = array(0 =>
    array(0 => 356050, 'appid' => 356050),
    1 => array(0 => 338040, ' appid' => 338040),
    2 => array(0 => 263920, 'appid' => 263920),
    3 => array(0 => 411740, 'appid' => 411740)
);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (in_array($appId, $value)) {
        echo 'Found';
    }
}
?>
```

Key specific search with return data: [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. The appid's in the array are always different for each user and changing.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using.

```
function searchAppID($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['appid'] === $id) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

This will work. You should call it like this:

```
$id = searchAppID('263920 ', $r);
```

If you have n-level of array then you can use above function with little modifications.
Please let me know if you need it.