# PHP search multidimensional array with two keys for value of 3rd key?

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I would think this is simple, searching a multidimensional array with two keys to bring back the value of the third.  I'm more confused then when I started and unable to get it to work.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [name] => Definite Position [Company_ID] => 4 [code] => DEF ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [name] => First Option [Company_ID] => 7 [code] => TNT ) ) 
[2] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [name] => Second Option [Company_ID] => 4 [code] => SEC ) ) 
[3] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [name] => Definite Out [Company_ID] => 6 [code] => DBO ) )
```

I would like to bring back the value of  [name] when I have [Company_ID] of 4 and [code] of 'SEC'

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a simple loop accessing the `data` index and then the indexes below that:

```
$id = 4;
$code = 'SEC';

foreach($array as $values) {
    if($values['data']['Company_ID'] == $id && $values['data']['code'] == $code) {
        $result = $values['data']['name'];
        break; // we found it no need to loop more
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I made it much more difficult then needed.  Works great!

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        "data" => array(
            "name" => "Definite Position",
            "Company_ID" => 4,
            "code" => "DEF"
        )
    ),
    array(
        "data" => array(
            "name" => "First Option",
            "Company_ID" => 7,
            "code" => "TNT"
        )
    ),
    array(
        "data" => array(
            "name" => "Second Option",
            "Company_ID" => 4,
            "code" => "SEC"
        )
    ),
    array(
        "data" => array(
            "name" => "Definite Out",
            "Company_ID" => 6,
            "code" => "DBO"
        )
    )
);

/**
 * Searches the array for matching criteria
 *
 * @param array $search Array of criteria to search for (eg. array("Company_ID" => 4, "code" => "SEC"))
 * @param array $array The array to search
 *
 * @return array The elements of the array that matched the criteria
 */

function search($search, $array)
{
    $retVal = array();
    foreach($array as $k => $v)
    {
        $found = true;
        foreach($search as $sKey => $sVal)
        {
            if ($v["data"][$sKey] != $sVal)
            {
                $found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($found)
            $retVal[]= $v;
    }

    return $retVal;
}

$results = search(
    array(
        "Company_ID" => 4,
        "code" => "SEC"
    ),
    $array
);

var_dump($results);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["data"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "Second Option"
      ["Company_ID"]=>
      int(4)
      ["code"]=>
      string(3) "SEC"
    }
  }
}
```