# get key from two multidimensional array whose values are equal

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a: Array
(
[161] => Array
    (
        [idAgent] => 30
        [idClient] => 97
    )

[163] => Array
    (
        [idAgent] => 30
        [idClient] => 107
    )

[712] => Array
    (
        [idAgent] => 12
        [idClient] => 349
    )

[718] => Array
    (
        [idAgent] => 12
        [idClient] => 57
    )

[721] => Array
    (
        [idAgent] => 9
        [idClient] => 236
    )

[729] => Array
    (
        [idAgent] => 12
        [idClient] => 118
    )

[739] => Array
    (
        [idAgent] => 20
        [idClient] => 483
    )
...
)

$b: Array
(
[160] => Array
    (
        [idAgent] => 31
        [idClient] => 926
    )

[162] => Array
    (
        [idAgent] => 30
        [idClient] => 97
    )
 ...
 )
```

I have two multidimensional arrays and I need to get the key whose array value belongs both $a and $b. In this case the result must be the array with 162 key.

```
$result: Array
(    
  [162] => Array
    (
        [idAgent] => 30
        [idClient] => 97
    )
...
)
```

I've tried, but without any luck, something like this:

```
array_intersect_uassoc( $a, $b, function ($A, $B){
    return ($A['idAgent'] - $B['idAgent']);
});
```

Or, it's better to create one multi array and then extract duplicates?

Comment: So only `idAgent` needs to match?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just [array_uintersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) (compares intersection of arrays by callback function).

The [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function in my example is just for easier comparison of strings.

If you need to search for unique combination of `idAgent` and `idClient`, put them as a string together for comparison.

```
$result = array_uintersect( $a, $b, function($A, $B){
    return strcmp($A['idAgent'] . '_' . $A['idClient'], $B['idAgent'] . '_' . $B['idClient']);
});
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that wouldn't be equal values (to the `idAgent` and `idClient` properties) as the OP has asked, so the function wouldn't see them as intersection.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh I see. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Correct, but I can't mark this as correct answer, because I do not have necessary reputation points. tx.