# Get whole array with keys and values where key equals value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have arrays in my JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":"bobbys_burgers",
        "is_enabled":true,
        "name":"Bobbys Burgers",
        "supported_transactions":[
            "222",
            "111",
            "333"
        ],
        "enrollment_required":[
        ],
        "restricted_transactions":[
            "123"
        ]
    },

    {
        "id":"randys_sandwich",
        "is_enabled":true,
        "name":"Randys Sandwich",
        "supported_transactions":[
            "321"
        ],
        "enrollment_required":[
        ],
        "restricted_transactions":[
        ]
    },
]
```

I want to get all the keys of the whole array where `id` = `randys_sandwich`. for example, i want to search for `id` == `randys_sandwich` and return the `is_enabled`, `name`, `supported_transactions`, etc AND their values from that array. how can i do that in php?

Comment: I got my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score -1):

You need to json_decode your array then loop through the objects in your array find the one with the id you're looking for.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($item in $array) {
  if ($item['id'] == 'randys_sandwich') {
    var_dump($item);
    break; // Once you've found the item no need to continue the loop
  }
}
```

Comment: i need the keys and values in php