# how to check whether 4 exist or not in array at 'id' key position

Tags: php, arrays

how to check whether 4 exist or not in array at `id` key position

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'other_data' => 'ganesh'
       ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'other_data' => 'ramesh'
       ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'other_data' => '4'
       ),
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: if that's your real code it should give you **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), expecting**

Comment: after each array in the array, add a comma `,`

Comment: `in_array(4, array_map(function($v) { return $v['id']; }, $arr))`

Answer (score 2):

The array you provided is not a valid multi-dimensional array. You need to add commas after each array in the array. Below i use `array_column` and `in_array` without using `foreach`

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'other_data' => 'ganesh'
           ),//add comma
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'other_data' => 'ramesh'
           ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'other_data' => '4'
           ),
    );


    $filtered = array_column($arr, 'id');//return the id column in this array

    if(in_array(4, $filtered)){//check if 4 exists
        echo '4 exists';
    } else {
     echo '4 does not exist';   
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple, loop through the array and check if the value exists:

```
$value = 4;
$exists = false;
foreach($arr as $innerArr){
  if($innerArr['id'] == $value){
    $exists = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

If `$exists` is now true, the value exists within the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, and let me know if you face any problem.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'other_data' => 'ganesh'
           ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'other_data' => 'ramesh'
           ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'other_data' => '4'
           )
    );

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array("4", $value))
      {
        $sub_index = $value['id'];
        echo "Match found at $sub_index";
        break;
      }
}
```

Just gotta loop through your array and check existence through in_array() function.

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this

```
$arr = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'other_data' => 'ganesh'
           ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'other_data' => 'ramesh'
           ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'other_data' => '4'
           )
    );
    $exists_flag = false;
    foreach($arr as $inside_arr)
    {
      if($inside_arr['other_data'] == 4) {
        $exists_flag = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    print($exists_flag);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As it stand, your array is wrong, you need to separate multi array with commas, you need to not that `in_array()` will not work with multi array, however you may create a recursive function that will check a provided key does exists or not in an array try code below, hope it helps `,`

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'other_data' => 'ganesh'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'other_data' => 'ramesh'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'other_data' => '4'
    )
);

function search_items($search_value, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (($item == $search_value) || (is_array($item) && search_items($search_value, $item))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

echo search_items("4", $arr) ? 'item found' : 'item not found';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_search(4, array_column($arr, 'id'));
```

If we split this into steps then it would be the following:

```
$allColumnsNamedId = array_column($arr, 'id'); // find all columns with key 'id'
$resultBoolean = array_search(4, $allColumnsNamedId); //search the array for value 4

if($resultBoolean) {
    echo 'Exists';   
} else {
   echo 'Does not exist';
}
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome! Please make sure to explain your reasoning behind your code suggestion. Why does this work?

Comment: Thanks Stef, I'll add more info :)