# get some values from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a multidimensional array with 4 to 5 levels and i want to extract some specific values from it

here is my array...

```
$tree = [
        "grandfather" => "Allah Bakhsh",
        "father" => [
            "Father_1" => "Akram",
                "child Akram" => [
                    "Child_1" => "Faisal",
                        "subchild faisal" => [
                            "subchild Faisal 1" => "Usama",
                            "subchild Faisal 2" => "Abdul Wali"
                        ],
                    "Child_2" => "Ali",
                        "subchild Ali" => [
                        "subchild" => "No Child"
                        ],
                ],


            "Father_2" => "Ashraf",
                "child Ashraf" => [
                    "Child_1" => "Sajid",
                        "subchild Sajid" => [
                            "subchild Sajid 1" => "Abdullah",
                            "subchild Sajid 2" => "Taha",
                            "subchild Sajid 3" => "Moosa"
                        ],
                    "Child_2" => "Majid",
                        "subchild Majid" => "No Child",


                ],

            "Father_3" => "Khalid",
                "child Khalid" => "No Child"
        ],
    ];
```

i want to get all values of

```
"Father_2" => "Ashraf",
```

i tried many times using foreach loop but cant done it.

kindly suggest something...

Comment: To avoid downvotes here, post your attempt too ;)

Comment: print_r($tree['father']['child Ashraf']);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: If you only want all value of `"Father_2" => "Ashraf"`, just do `var_dump($tree['father']['father_2']);`, no?

Comment: @SanjayKumar it works good