# Get only a matched key value from array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, nested

I have an array result like this.

```
Array
(
    [Bank] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bank
            [status] => 1
            [enable_rcb] => 1
        )

    [Cod] => Array
        (
            [name] => Cod
            [status] => 1
            [enable_rcb] => 0
        )

    [Lite] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lite
            [status] => 0
            [enable_rcb] => 0
        )
)
```

I want to get result from conditional. For example I want show only Bank if the status is 1 and leave the rest array.
I try to show them like this

```
        $results = array();
        foreach ($user_pay as $value) {
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                if($value['status']=="1"){
                    $user_payment[] = $value['name'];
                }
            }
            $results = $user_payment;
        }
```

But the result give me duplicate result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bank
    [1] => Bank
    [2] => Bank
    [3] => Bank
    [4] => Bank
    [5] => Bank
    [6] => Cod
    [7] => Cod
    [8] => Cod
    [9] => Cod
    [10] => Cod
)
```

What I want is to get the name of an array which is have status 1 and it should be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bank
    [1] => Cod
)
```

How to avoid this duplicate result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search by key=>value in a multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019076/how-to-search-by-key-value-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: After editing my answer below, I realized something weird: how come you can have duplicates if the names are also your array's keys? You can't have the same twice.

Comment: Your inner loop can just be removed `foreach ($value as $k => $v) {` - you don't even use the values from this loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change loop such that

```
$results = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value):
    if($value["status"]){
      $results[] = $value["name"];
    }
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, this code is very simple, I thought it need a nested, in fact no.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) to retrieve only the ones with the desired status, then [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/array_column) to grab their names:

```
$filtered = array_filter($arr, static function ($entry) {
  return $entry['status'] === 1;
});

$names = array_column($filtered, 'name');
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/Nhc0P**

Comment: thanks for help, but this result as null value and give me a blank page

Comment: @GregoriRasputin As you can check in the provided link, this works fine unless you're on PHP 5.5.0 or below (in which case, I highly recommend you upgrade).

Comment: yes, I'm on php 5 right now, Upgrade means change all code in my file?

Comment: @GregoriRasputin No I mean upgrading to PHP7. This can take a bit of time depending on your codebase, but you'll get way better performance, stability, and features. PHP5 isn't even supported anymore. (And if you absolutely can't, at the very least upgrade to PHP5.6, this answer will work fine with it.)

Comment: Thanks. You give me best suggestion. I will update it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach it like

```
$new = array_keys(array_filter($a,function($v){
  return $v['status'] > 0;
}));

print_r($new);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/5rQjm

Comment: can I do with multiple condition? Like if status 1 and enable_rcb 1 then show the name

Comment: @GregoriRasputin Yes you can, just put like this `$v['status'] > 0 && $v['enable_rcb'] 
 ==1`

Answer (score -1):

You can use **array_unique()**

```
$result = array_unique($result);
```